# How to handle timepicker selection in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, object

I have timerange  fields `timefrom` and `timetill`

`timefrom` should not be greater than `timetill`

Only after selecting `timefrom` and `timetill`, the value should be displayed to the textarea.

for example,
If the `timefrom` - "1:00" and `timetill` - 4:00 is chosen, it is displayed to the textarea.
then empty the `timefrom` and `timetill` for next selection

here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import TimeComponent from "./TimeComponent"
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TimeComponent/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/optimistic-spence-4jnuk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: timetill should be greater i guess you mean. also, what is the target? to clear the fields after entering the range in textarea?

Comment: Could you explain exactly what is not working from the codesandbox link? Might help us debug :)

Comment: @Apostolos  Antonio Erdelijac, on every time range selection, once added in textarea, empty the timefrom and timetill,

Comment: @Apostolos yes, clear the fields after entering the range in textarea

Comment: @codecat check my answer. i think this is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to call the `buttonHanlder` method on `onClose` method of `TimePicker`. This means that when you have selected the time you need and press somewhere else to close the popup, it will trigger this event and then it should update the state (if of course both time entries are not empty)

```
          <TimePicker
            onClose={this.buttonHanlder}
            value={
              moment(this.state.timeto, "HH:mm").isValid()
                ? moment(this.state.timeto, "HH:mm")
                : ""
            }
            onChange={time => this.handleChange(time, "timeto")}
            showSecond={false}
          />
```

and remove the call at `handleChange`

Check this sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-flower-4ph42

Comment: yes it works, thanks but it allows to add in textarea if timefrom is greater than timetill, (should not allow)

Comment: yes didnt add validation for that only focused on how to add when both entries were selected :)

Comment: it shouldnt be difficult to add such validation though